# Pandas conditionally set value based on string column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with locations and values set by various outputs. I also have a column that tells me which column I want to use. something like this:

```
location x y z best
detroit  1 2 3  x
chicago  3 4 5  y
racine   2 4 3  z
```

I want to set the value of a new column based on the value of "best"

something like

```
location x y z best val
detroit  1 2 3  x    1
chicago  3 4 5  y    4
racine   2 4 3  z    3
```

How do I do that? No nested functions, custom functions or for loops allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['val'] = df[['x','y','z']].lookup(df.index, df['best'])
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
  location  x  y  z best  val
0  detroit  1  2  3    x    1
1  chicago  3  4  5    y    4
2   racine  2  4  3    z    3
```

**Alternative:**

```
df['val']=df[['x','y','z']].stack().loc[zip(df.index, df['best'])].values
```